# Objective C - addTarget:selector:forControlEvents: not working

Tags: ios, objective-c

So I have 2 classes(FirstClass and SecondClass). FirstClass is a UIViewController, and SecondClass is a NSObject class. In the FirstClass i have a button -- dialButton.

In the SecondClass, I call a method that I made in the FirstClass (test)

printPrompt is where I call the method test.

printPrompt:

```
FirstClass *firstClass =[[FirstClass alloc]init];
[firstClass test];
```

test:

```
SecondClass *secondClass = [[SecondClass alloc]init];
[dialButton removeTarget:self selector:@selector(firstClassMethod) forControlEvent: UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[dialButton addTarget:secondClass selector:@selector(secondClassMethod)         
forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

secondClassMethod is not called when i click the button after calling test.. rather, the program crashes.

secondClassMethod:

```
FirstClass *firstClass = [[FirstClass alloc]init]; 
[firstClass setString: @"Test"];
```

setString just changes a UIText Field. I've tested it and setString: works.

There are no compile-time errors.

Comment: Provides details about the crash.

Comment: Have you made the firstClassMethod publicly accessible in the @interface header?

Comment: The program just crashes... the method secondClassMethod is never called @rmaddy

Comment: Yes, otherwise there would be a compile-time error @remus

Comment: Yes, and when it crashes it should tell your where and you should get an error message. If not, see http://raywenderlich.com/10209/my-app-crashed-now-what-part-1

Comment: BTW - the crash most likely indicates that `secondClassMethod` is being called. The problem is either there is no such method or, more likely, the `secondClass` instance was deallocated.

Comment: exc_bad_acess @rmaddy

Comment: Read Naveen's answer and turn on zombies checking prove he is correct.

Comment: I understand his answer.. but how to fix it? @rmaddy

Comment: You fix it by ensuring the object doesn't get deallocated too soon. Typically done using an instance variable to keep a reference.

Answer (score 1):

Your second class is in method test and the object secondClass  would be released after test is completed (If you are using ARC).

Double check your design whether you want to do this.

First Class

```
@interface FirstClass : UIViewController
{
    UIButton *dialButton;
}
@property (nonatomic, strong) SecondClass *secondClass;

@end


@implementation FirstClass

-(void) viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

   self.secondClass = [[SecondClass alloc] init];
   self.secondClass.firstClass = self;
}

-(void) firstClassMethod
{

}

-(void) testClass
{
   [dialButton removeTarget:self action:@selector(firstClassMethod) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside ];
   [dialButton addTarget:self.secondClass action:@selector(secondClassMethod) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
}
@end
```

Second Class

```
@interface SecondClass : NSObject
@property (nonatomic, strong) FirstClass *firstClass;

-(void) secondClassMethod;

@end


@implementation SecondClass

-(void) secondClassMethod
{

}
@end
```

Comment: so how do i fix this problem?

Comment: Declare second class as a class level variable and use it.

Comment: That will fix crash, There is another problem since you are instantiating the FirstClass again in `secondClassMethod` the text field value would not change. To achieve your result, declare a property '@property (nonatomic,strong) FirstClass *firstClass` in second class and assign it after instantiating SecondClass like `secondClass.firstClass = self`. This would help you to achieve what you expect. However request you to rethink your design.

Comment: Can I declare a property instaead? @NaveenprasadR

Comment: Because doesnt it need to be alloc/init?

Comment: Ok.. thanks! Please look at Leoformaggio's answer that I commented on. It seems as though when I try to make it a property, it does not work.

Answer (score 0):

You are creating new instances of your classes where you should reference the original ones. In this case, you should add a property in each class, to access `FirstClass` from `SecondClass` and vise-versa. Somenthing like the following:

```
@interface FirstClass : UIViewController {
    UIButton *dialButton;
}

@property (nonatomic, strong) SecondClass *secondClass;

- (void)firstClassMethod;
- (void)test;
- (void)setString:(NSString *)string;

@end

@implementation FirstClass

- (void)firstClassMethod
{
    // ...
}

- (void)test
{
    [dialButton removeTarget:self action:@selector(firstClassMethod) forControlEvent:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [dialButton addTarget:self.secondClass action:@selector(secondClassMethod) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
}

@interface SecondClass : NSObject

@property (nonatomic, strong) FirstClass *firstClass;

- (void)printPrompt;
- (void)secondClassMethod;

@end

@implementation SecondClass

- (void)printPrompt
{
    if (!self.firstClass) {
        self.firstClass = [[FirstClass alloc] init];
        self.firstClass.secondClass = self;
    }
    [self.firstClass test];
}

- (void)secondClassMethod
{
    [self.firstClass setString:@"Test"];
}

@end
```

Comment: what type of property?

Comment: @stackoverflowuser01 I just edited my answer with a sample code. I don't know exactly your needs, so it's based on your description.

Comment: It doesnt seem to be working... there is a compile-time error when i try to create the property. Btw, the firstClass was an arbitrary name.. its actually ViewController.

Comment: What's the error? Did you added `#import "FirstClass.h"` or `@class FirstClass;` in your .h?

Comment: Yes I did, I added the Import.. how do i check the error? It just says Unkown type name ViewController.. suggests to change to UIViewController

Comment: Is there a class named `ViewController` in your project? If not, change this name to `UIViewController` as the error suggests.

Comment: There is a class named ViewController.